# Read status code on response from asp.net core in angular 6

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, http, asp.net-core

I have an API in Asp.net core 2 and I need catch the status code from the response, but on my response in angular only have my API result.

My method on API

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("cadastrar-categoria")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CadastrarCategoriaAsync([FromBody]Categoria item)
    {
        try
        {
            var sucesso = await _service.CadastroCategoria(item);
            if (sucesso == 1)
            {
                return Ok("Sucesso");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Erro");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And my Service in angular

```
CadastrarCategoria(nome: string) {
 let data = new CadastroCategoriaDto();
 data.Nome = nome;

 return this.req
   .post(environment.urls.cadastrarProduto, data)
   .subscribe((res: Response) => {
     console.log(res);
   });
```

}

My response in the browser is only this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpDFW.png)

How I catch the status code from this response?
example in return Ok() I need receive status code 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want full response in subscribe method then use `{observe: 'response'}`.

Example:

```
return this.req
   .post(environment.urls.cadastrarProduto, data,{observe: 'response'})
   .subscribe((res: HttpResponse) => {
     console.log(res.status);
   });
```